# How Can I Show Exception Message in Custom Error Page in WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, aspx-user-control

I have written a code in webforms to redirect to the custom error page in `web.config` file.

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/StatusCode500.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

And I have written a code which gives me database error.

[image]

and the code for StatusCode500 is:

```
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h1 style="color: #00AEC0">Oops..Could not connect to Database. </h1>
        </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h4 style="color: #00AEC0">Please contact your Network Administrator</h4>
        </div>
```

It works absolutely fine, but now what I need is I need to pass the exceptional message (Divided by zero error in this case) to the StatusCode500 page just below Please contact you network administrator . How can I pass that exceptional message or Error Id?

Comment: Generally this is something you shouldn't do. Just give the user a generic user message and tell them to contact help. Log the exception details somewhere so that the help will have the details behind what's going on. If you're really sophisticated, you could even show the user an ErrorId that you associate to the logged event, so which will aid the help in correlating the exact error they experienced.

Comment: @mason yeah errorID will work for me. How Can I show error ID in this case?

Comment: You'll have to go implement that if it's what you want to do.

Comment: Put the message in the `Exception.Data` property.